# hibernate enverse : how to get changed value in relation field

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

i am using hibernate enverse 5.2.10.Final with postgres data base.

```
AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
        String newValue = (String) auditReader.createQuery()
                .forEntitiesAtRevision(Vehicle.class, 2203869)
                .traverseRelation("vehicleType", JoinType.INNER).addProjection(AuditEntity.property("id")).up()
                .add(AuditEntity.property("vehicleType").hasChanged())              
                .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(2203422l))
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().eq(2203869)).getSingleResult();
```

vehicle table has many-to-one relationship with vehicleType.
how to get the changes of vehicle type property of vehicle entity using enverse query.
here i get no result found error.
cannot get get value with Audientity.property("vehicleType")..hasChanged()
their's a error property not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
auditReader.createQuery()
  .forEntitiesAtRevision( Vehicle.class, revisionNumber )                                           
  .traverseRelation( propertyname, JoinType.LEFT )
  .addProjection( AuditEntity.property("id") ).up()
  .add( AuditEntity.property( propertyname ).hasChanged() )
  .add( AuditEntity.id().eq( VehicleId ) )                                  
  .getSingleResult()
```